# How do i perform calculation about the last n observations

Tags: sas

how can i perform calculation for the last n observation in a data set
For example if I have 10 observations I would like to create a variable that would sum the last 5 values of another variable. Please do not suggest that I lag 5 times or use module ( *N* ). I need a bit more elegant solution than that.

with the code below alpha is the data set that i have and bravo is the one i need.

```
data alpha; 
    input lima @@ ;
    cards ;
3 1 4 21 3 3 2 4 2 5
; 
run ;

data bravo;
input lima juliet;
cards;
3 .
1 .
4 .
21 .
3 32
3 32
2 33
4 33
2 14
5 16
;
run;
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone reads this :)
I solved it the way I needed it to be solved. Although now I am more curious which of the two(the retain and my solution) is more optimal in terms of computing/processing time.

Here is my solution:

```
data bravo(keep = var1 summ);
    set alpha;
    do i=_n_ to _n_-4 by -1;
        set alpha(rename=var1=var2) point=i;
        summ=sum(summ,var2);        
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the data step or using PROC EXPAND from SAS/ETS if available.

For the data step the idea is that you start with a cumulative sum (`summ`), but keep track of the number of values that were added so far (`ninsum`). Once that reaches 5, you start outputting the cumulative sum to the target variable (`juliet`), and from the next step you start subtracting the lagged-5 value to only store the sum of the last five values.

```
data beta;
    set alpha;
    retain summ ninsum 0;

    summ + lima;
    ninsum + 1;
    l5 = lag5(lima);

    if ninsum = 6 then do;
        summ = summ - l5;
        ninsum = ninsum - 1;
    end;

    if ninsum = 5 then do;
        juliet = summ;
    end;

run;

proc print data=beta;
run;
```

However there is a procedure that can do all kind of cumulative, moving window, etc calculations: PROC EXPAND, in which this is really just one line. We just tell it to calculate the backward moving sum in a window of width 5 and set the first 4 observations to missing (by default it will expand your series by 0's on the left).

```
proc expand data=alpha out=gamma;
       convert lima = juliet   / transformout=(movsum 5 trimleft 4);
 run;

proc print data=gamma;
run;
```

**Edit**

If you want to do more complicated calculations, you need to carry the previous values in retained variables. I thought you wanted to avoid that, but here it is:

```
data epsilon;
    set alpha;
    array lags {5};
    retain lags1 - lags5;

    /* do whatever calculation is needed */
    juliet = 0;
    do i=1 to 5;
        juliet = juliet + lags{i};
    end;

    output;

    /* shift over lagged values, and add self at the beginning */
    do i=5 to 2 by -1;
        lags{i} = lags{i-1};
    end;
    lags{1} = lima;

    drop i;
run;

proc print data=epsilon;
run;
```

Comment: Very useful indeed. I did not know about proc expand's functionallity. Althought this is only example. I intend to perform much complicated calculation taking into account the last "n" observations and I was wondering if there was a way to do that without lagging the different variables n times. If you have any additional suggestions, please share them. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't know what a DOW loop is, but I have added another solution that allows for arbitrary calculation on the last "n" observations.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of the posts :) I think I am going to go with the lags. It is most appropriate for what i am trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

I can offer rather ugly solution:

1. run data step and add increasing number to each **group**.
2. run sql step and add column of **max(group)**.
3. run another data step and check if value from (2)-(1) is less than 5. If so, assign to **_num_to_sum_** variable (for example) the value that you want to sum, otherwise leave it blank or assign 0.
4. and last do a sql step with **sum(_num_to_sum_)** and group results by grouping variable from (1).

**EDIT:** I have added a live example of the concept in a bit more compacted way.

```
input var1 $ var2;
cards;
aaa 3
aaa 5
aaa 7
aaa 1
aaa 11
aaa 8
aaa 6
bbb 3
bbb 2
bbb 4
bbb 6
;
run;

data step1;
    set sourcetable;
    by var1;
    retain obs 0;
    if first.var1 then obs = 0;
    else obs = obs+1;
    if obs >=5 then to_sum = var2;
run;

proc sql;
    create table rezults as
        select distinct var1, sum(to_sum) as needed_summs
        from step1
        group by var1;
quit;
```

Comment: Thnaks, every post is appriciated. And its not that ugly. I like it ;]

Comment: Upvoting my answer then would be nice =)

Comment: It requires 15 rep :D Sry I am new. And btw I could not perform your solution. I could find a proper sql aggregation variable if _n_ is divisible by 5 then count+1 for instance that way it is kinda easy. I would like to do it with a few arrays,retain or set commands if possible

Comment: see my addition to initial answer, hope it helps.

Comment: This is not the problem at all. I need the sum of the last 5 oservation. Each record in the new var should contain the sum of the last 5 observation from the old variable, there is no variable in the data set to be used for grouping. Imagine a data set with one column all numbers. You have to create a second column with the first 4 obs missing, becuase there are no 5 observation which to be summed. For the 5th observation for column 2 the value should be the sum of the last 5 observation, the 6th observation,column 2 should be the sum of the 6th 5th 4th 3rd 2nd observation from column 1 etc.